# How do I remove the requirement for a file extension on my site

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

I've been checking through docs, Stack Overflow, and google for a few hours now. Also, dipped in and out of a few IRC channels.

I'm a pretty big newbie when it comes to editing these documents, so bear with me on this.
I mean, when you say 'httpd.conf' I have looked for it. It doesn't exist. So, please tell me if it really is apache2.conf or what the file name is.

So, I switched from Ubuntu to Kali Linux.  I've been developing a website, and up until now, I have never had to add .php to the end of my URL. However, now, seemingly out of the blue, I get 404's if it's not included.

```
example: This is what I have to do

[URL: localhost/videos.php]

This is what I want to do

[URL: localhost/videos]
```

How do I fix this?

The things I have tried:

Both in and out of multiple dir blocks:

```
[/phpmyadmin/apache.conf]
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews

[.htaccess]
mod_rewrite just causes E_500's left and right.

[/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf]
[*] mod_rewrite
[*] Options Multivews
```

It would be extremely appreciated if someone could help me out,
I've been dealing with it all day, and I need to get this working
so I can finish up the rest of the project.

[Edit: An actual answer VS messing with my post in a non-helpful manner. Try the first one instead next time.]

Comment: `mod_rewrite` is activated in `Apache` ?

Comment: Could you edit the question title and change it to something more descriptive?

Comment: Try adding `Options +MultiViews` line on top of your .htaccess and then retest.

Comment: It still comes up with a 404 when I added Options +Multiviews

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the files on your server have the `.php` extension and that there is a file handler somewhere that pulls those pages through php. I am also guessing that if you have a file `test.php` in your www-root, you can still access it by going to `example.com/test.php`.

First of all make sure that `mod_rewrite` is enabled in your server config. `mod_rewrite.so` must be in the correct folder and the line `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` (or something similar) should be uncommented. Make sure to restart Apache when making changes to the main config file. Those are loaded at startup, and not dynamically executed like `.htaccess` does. Make sure that the `FollowSymLinks` option is enabled in the `.htaccess` in your www-root. `AllowOverride` must at least be set to `FileInfo` in your `httpd.conf` (or whatever functions as the main configuration file).

Then this rule should work. It tests if a file doesn't end on a file extension and internally rewrites it to the same file with `.php` appended.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[a-z]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

If you still get Internal Server errors, look in your Apache error log. It will tell you exactly what happened before the error occurred.

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm looking for, friend. I made an edit in the top, but basically [localhost/videos] is a 404, due to not being specific and putting [localhost/videos.php].

Comment: I think you want to edit that rewrite to exclude URL's that already end in .php
Otherwise, @DouglasHarding this is what you need.

Comment: That's still creating a 500 error. I just found out how to turn AllowOverride ALL, which didn't really fix anything.

Comment: @aross Unless you want to rewrite `/myjavascriptfile.js` to `/myjavascriptfile.js.php` that *shouldn't* be the case! I've excluded *every* file extension for a reason, because if a file has a file extension, it can be assumed it has the correct file extension.

Comment: @Sumurai8 good point, I was assuming file URLs managed through the application, but that's probably not the case here.

Comment: Even better in this case would be this though:   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d